# How can I identify the class of an abstract object being an argument to a function?

Tags: java, abstract-class, instanceof, abstract-data-type

I am trying to make a function that sifts through an array of objects that inherit from one abstract class. The function takes in the item to look for as an argument of the abstract class type, and, if it finds the object type, it deletes it. Here is the code:

```
public void removeItem(MPItem itemDelete){
    for (int i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++){
        if(myItems[i] instanceof itemDelete){
            myItems[i] = null;
            break;
        }
        
        //If it reaches this point, we hit the end of the array with no item matching.
        if(i == myItems.length - 1){
            System.out.println("Item to delete not found");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that by typing *instanceof* in the if statement, it tries to find a class named itemDelete, which does not exist. I am trying to make it to where, no matter what item type I pass in the function that are children of the MPItem abstract class, it will see what exact child class it is, find the first instance of that child type in the array, set it to null, and exit the function. Can anyone help with this or direct me to something that will? Thanks!

Comment: I think you might be looking into using Java Generics.

Comment: I don't think this line of your code compiles: `if(myItems[i] instanceof itemDelete)` The thing after `instanceof` should be the name of a class or interface and not the name of a variable. In any case, if you want the exact type of a variable, call method `getClass()`, as in `itemDelete.getClass()`

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, itemDelete passed in as a child class ovject of the abstract class MPItem. I want to search the array for an object of that class I passed in and delete it.

Comment: @Abra Yes, the code I originally have in there does not work, it's mainly just a placeholder for what I want to do. Also, I have tried adding getClass() to the end of itemDelete in that instanceof check. It does not work, saying ')' expected, illegal start of expression, and ';' expected, which leads me to believe I am simply using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that myItems is defined like this:

```
MPItems[] myItems = ...
```

You can use generics and the `isAssignableFrom` method to achieve your goal:

```
public void removeItem(Class<? extends MPItem> itemDelete){
    for (int i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++) {
        if (myItems[i].getClass().isAssignableFrom(itemDelete)){
            myItems[i] = null;
            break;
        }

        //If it reaches this point, we hit the end of the array with no item matching.
        if (i == myItems.length - 1){
            System.out.println("Item to delete not found");
        }
    }
}
```

To call the function, do this:

```
foo.removeItem(Something.class);
```

Side note: `myItems[i] = null` is not actually deleting anything from the array (at least not in the normal sense). It is simply setting that position in the array to be null (maybe this is actually what you want). If you actually want to remove the element from the array, here is an alternative solution:

```
public void removeItem(Class<? extends MPItem> itemDelete){
    myItems = Stream.of(myItems).filter(i -> !i.getClass().isAssignableFrom(itemDelete)).toArray(MPItem[]::new);
}
```

However, since this method is reassigning myItems, it may break other parts of your code :/

Comment: Side side note: your method is only going to "remove" the first object it finds from the array before the loop breaks (Maybe this is what you want?). I might be seriously misunderstanding your goals here, but it seems like you should really be using a ```List``` instead of an array.

Comment: In the arguments, do you recommend putting my class MPItem in place of "Script"? Sorry if that's a dumb question, I am very new to generics. I am struggling to find java documentation on that kind of argument initialization.

Comment: @Axsis That was my bad, I changed the code to fix this, go ahead and reload your page.

Comment: you are correct in your assumption, and yes I probably should be doing something differently, I just don't have a lot of experience with those kind of concepts. I wanted a fixed array length, which I am not sure if you can do that in Lists

Comment: @Axsis So you want a fixed array length, but also want to be able to remove elements? Not sure I understand the structure you are going for...

Comment: the idea, if you have ever played a game like Mario Party, is for a player to have 3 slots for items at all times, no more, no less. I am trying to make a simulator of Mario Party so I can evaluate how powerful things in game are (like items) without having to playtest the game myself. In this moment, I am trying to make it where, if the AI uses an item, it is removed from the player's inventory while still maintaining the length constraints of the array. I don't exactly want to "remove" those elements entirely, just remove their reference so the item "isn't there anymore"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246657/discussion-between-volt4-and-axsis).